# How to set custom environment variable for run script

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcodebuild

How to set a custom variable from command line which will be available in the script executed by build phases.
I have a run script in my Xcode project's Build Phases who's operation depend on the value of this custom variable.

So from Jenkins, I want to set the environment variable

```
MYVARIABLE="some value"
```

Which will be used by the run script

Answer (score 0):

In global properties you can set environments. Please check https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-environment-variables